# GA landing pages (not set), but URI is known AND organic traffic down, direct/none up?

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, uri

I need help troubleshooting 2 main issues with our Google Analytics data. Both started occurring around May 5, 2020. I've worked through troubleshooting recommendations in few blog posts but have had no luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to troubleshoot these issues?

1. Organic traffic has dropped considerably on our /blog/ pages while direct/none traffic has increased. When I check Google Search Console's organic search data, I see numbers that reflect the organic + direct/none traffic in google analytics.
2. When I look at the landing page report, there is a huge increase in (not set) landing pages on our blog. I saw 14,000% and 26,000% increases... Our overall landing page traffic is down by 15%. Weirdly, the URI is known, but the landing page is (not set)...?

Please check out this video to see the data in GA - http://m.bixel1.net/jxe9ei

One potential cause is that we have a homepage redirect for anyone using chrome. The redirect goes from / to /c/ for anyone on chrome and is hard coded. We've been testing this since the beginning of the year and we switched the test to serve to 100% of chrome visitors on March 26, 2020. Could this possibly be causing our traffic issues?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect certainly creates anomalies (consider that when landing on the page both / and /c/ are tracked).

I noticed, for example by accessing a blog page from google, that the pageview has no referrer while the events sent after 30 seconds have it (and it is google.com).
Check your configuration in Google Tag Manager if there is any strange setting on the referral or something configured that can interfere with the referrer.

In any case, this (referrer) is surely the reason why you have the *(not set)*.